# Listing and Classifying Permutations of a Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I would like to ask if there is any classification method to classify the types of permutation elements of a Symmetric group $S_n$ for easy listing of the members in this group.

Comment: The most natural classification method is by cycle type. But that is probably not the easiest way to list its elements, which you can do just by using the lexicographical ordering on permutations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to list the elements of the symmetric group is by a recursive process. Notice that if you delete $n$ from a permutation in $S_n$ in one line notation you get an element of $S_{n-1}$. You can use this to go in the other direction too.

Start with
$$1$$
Then we want to insert the $2$. There are two places to do this.
$$\mathbf 21$$
and
$$1\mathbf 2$$
Then let's take $21$ and insert a $3$. There are $3$ ways to do this.
$$\mathbf 321$$
$$2\mathbf 31$$
$$21\mathbf 3$$
I'm sure you see how to continue.